# Silverlight first steps

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to build a new website. I would like to use Silverlight.
How do I start a Silverlight website?
Where can I find a step by step tutorial?

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/

http://silverlightugstarter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[www.silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net) would be a good place to start looking around.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a fantastic new training kit available here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/